# Why does the graph get inverted in Excel when I Normalise the y axis

Tags: excel, graph

Before Normalisation:
[image: table before normalisation]

[image: graph before normalisation]

After Normalisation

[image: table after normalisation]
[image: graph after Normalisation]

Comment: Because your baselines are different?  This is not unexpected, just math.

Comment: But won't this be a misinterpretation because the brown line should be maximum

Comment: Why should the brown line be maximum in your normalized data?  After normalization each method is represented relative to its own performance at 2 bytes, so the performance at that point will affect the rest of the line.